# Why Should I pass in dispatch as a dependency of useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I've seen a lot of projects that use dispatch as a dependency of useEffect hook in react and I wondered that dispatch is a function and why should I pass it inside useEffect hook?

I guess this is because of our store, I meant it's a reference to our store.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to pass `dispatch` as a dependency. The returned references from hooks are known as 'closed-over' or 'captured' values, meaning that the 'hook' in use maintains the references it returns. In the case of useDispatch, its captured reference must remain the same during the lifetime of the component. One of the triggers for a re-render in `useEffect` is when the arguments you pass as references change.

With that said, it doesn't make any difference to your code whether you use it as a dependency or not. Usually, in VSCode, it will give you an error if you don't use it, but that is an ESLint error, and we comply with it.

If you go to https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks and scroll useDispatch's info section it states the following: "The `dispatch` function reference will be stable as long as the same store instance is being passed to the `<Provider>`. Normally, that store instance **never changes** in an application. However, the React hooks **lint rules do not know that `dispatch` should be stable**, and will warn that the `dispatch` variable should be added to dependency arrays for `useEffect` and `useCallback`. **The simplest solution is to do just that**:"

Comment: So is there any way that dispatch could change?

Comment: If for some reason you created a new store at runtime and passed it into your `<Provider>`, that would cause dispatch to change. But that's not something that apps normally do. If you're not doing anything weird like that, then `dispatch` will not change.

Comment: @AmirAryanmehr - The captured function (dispatch) obtained through useDispatch is fundamental to the Redux store and typically remains constant in a typical Redux application. However, there are certain edge cases where it can change. These scenarios include Hot Module Replacement (HMR) or live reload packages, custom middleware that modifies dispatch behaviour, resetting application state, and when dispatch is mocked for testing purposes. In a production environment, the dispatch function should remain consistent and not change.

Comment: "The returned references from hooks are known as 'closed-over' or 'captured' values, meaning that the 'hook' in use maintains the references it returns." - This is only true in React function components for a single render cycle. When the function is called again on the next render cycle, variables are redeclared. The value passed to them *may* or *may not* be a stable value between renders. The rest of your answer doesn't make much sense either, or merely points out the obvious that the OP is asking about without explaining anything.

Comment: @Drew Reese - If you go to https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks and scroll useDispatch's info section it states the following: 
"The dispatch function reference will be stable as long as the same store instance is being passed to the <Provider>. Normally, that store instance never changes in an application.
However, the React hooks lint rules do not know that dispatch should be stable, and will warn that the dispatch variable should be added to dependency arrays for useEffect and useCallback. The simplest solution is to do just that:"

Answer (score -2):

In many React projects that utilize a state management library like Redux or React Context, the dispatch function is often passed as a dependency to the useEffect hook. This is because the dispatch function is typically used to update the state or trigger actions in the store.

When you include dispatch as a dependency of the useEffect hook, it ensures that the effect will re-run whenever the dispatch function changes. This is important because if the dispatch function changes, it usually means that the state management library has been updated or reconfigured in some way.

By including dispatch as a dependency, you can handle specific side effects or perform certain actions in response to state changes or dispatched actions. This is a common pattern in Redux or React Context-based applications, where you may want to respond to changes in the store's state or dispatch additional actions based on certain conditions.

However, it's worth mentioning that including dispatch as a dependency in every useEffect hook might not always be necessary. In some cases, you may only need to include specific state variables or other dependencies that directly affect the behavior of the effect. It's important to consider the specific requirements of your component and determine which dependencies are truly necessary for your effect to function correctly.

Comment: how can the state management library be updated or reconfigured?

Comment: It's wrong, [dispatch is never necessary in the dependency array](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch). And your answer looks AI generated.

Comment: In most cases, it's sufficient to rely on the initial reference of the dispatch function captured in the closure of the component. This reference remains stable throughout the component's lifecycle, allowing you to use it within the useEffect hook or other parts of the component.

Comment: you are correct in many cases